# How can I assign an order value to rows in a table based on a value of frequence contained in a column

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [Kana]         NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [Kanji]        NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [FrequencyA]   INT              NULL,
    [OrderA]       INT              NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PhrasePhraseChapter] FOREIGN KEY ([ChapterId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PhraseChapter] ([PhraseChapterShortId])
);
```

The Freq column contains a number from 0 to 20,000.

Is there a way that I can populate the [OrderA] column so as to assign a position to each row. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
PhraseId     FrequencyA     OrderA
1            100             3   
2            50              4
3            50              5
4            201             1
5            200             2
6            10              7
7            50              6
```

I realize this is rather difficult to explain so please ask any questions if the question is not clear and I will try to clarify. Note that for the case of the row with the Order of 50 I am not concerned about the order for the PhraseId of 2,3 and 7 as long as one of them appears as the 4th, another the 5th and another the 6th.  I have about 15,000 rows so slight differences like this will not make any difference.

Comment: This is yet another post in a series of many around the same "project" (the quotes being there for the benefit of the doubt). Show us any sign that you actually try to solve your issues before asking here, otherwise it is just as you expect the community to work for free for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RANKING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189798.aspx) functions to get the desired result.

Adding the code here.

```
SELECT PhraseId, FrequencyA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL) ORDER BY FrequencyA DESC) AS OrderA
FROM Phrase
ORDER BY PhraseId
```

Note: I want to highlight that the colunm `PhraseId` is a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, which will not show the numbers as integers as shown in the example, instead it will show `GUID`.

Adding the UPDATE Query.

```
;WITH PhraseUpdate
AS
(
  SELECT PhraseId, FrequencyA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL) ORDER BY FrequencyA DESC) AS OrderA
  FROM Phrase
)
UPDATE p
SET  OrderA = pu.OrderA
FROM PhraseUpdate pu
JOIN Phrase p
ON p.PhraseId = pu.PhraseId
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I populate the column?

Comment: @Anne, You can use update statement to update the column.